# How to develop the EKC regression model?

Tags: regression, environmental-data

I want to use the environmental Kuznets curve (EKC) to check the relationship between increase economic growth and environmental degradation, but I am faced with a challenge on how and where to build this model. Can I develop an EKC model in Eviews and what are the steps to follow when building an EKC model?

Comment: Are you looking to fit a specific functional form or only a more general "increasing then decreasing" function?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have never used this method before. please, I need some basis on how to develop a specific model.